# Bibliography with custom data model not printing

Tags: biblatex, genealogy

I previously asked a question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/438759/how-to-set-up-biblatex-for-use-with-freeform-citations) and received a very useful reply which solved (most of) my dilemma. I have realised, however, that the bibliography is not printing when I use `crossref` in a 'master' entry in my `.bib` file. These 'master' or 'dummy' entries are used for those sources which would otherwise make duplicate bibliography entries simply due to their broad nature.

Below is my minimum working example showing two source citation entries - one which prints and one which does not - and the master source citation.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{freeform.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{freeform}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  bibliography,
  cite,
  firstcite,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[freeform]{
  bibliography,
  cite,
  firstcite,
  sortkey,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber, datamodel=freeform]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{freeform}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{bibliography}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \ifentrytype{freeform}
    {\iffieldundef{firstcite}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
       {\printfield{firstcite}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
     \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
       \usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifentrytype{freeform}
    {\printfield{cite}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=false]{
    \map{
      \pertype{freeform}
      \step[fieldsource=bibliography]
      \step[fieldset=sortkey, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@freeform{baptism,
  cite         = {Church of England (Spondon, Derbs.), Parish Registers, vol.\ 9, p.\ 1, Thompson (9 June 1824).},
  firstcite    = {Church of England (Spondon, Derbyshire, England), Parish Registers, vol.\ 9, p.\ 1, baptism of Emma Thompson (9 June 1824); digital images, Ancestry.com (\url{http://ancestry.com.au}: accessed 4 July 2018), citing Derbyshire Record Office, Matlock.},
  bibliography = {Church of England (Spondon, Derbyshire, England). Parish Registers. Digital images. \textit{Ancestry.com}. \url{http://ancestry.com.au}: 2018},
  keywords     = {church}
}
@freeform{marriage,
  cite         = {Church of England (Derby, Derbs.), Parish Registers, vol.\ 4, p.\ 3, Smith-Bloggs (20 January 1815).},
  firstcite    = {Church of England (Derby, Derbyshire, England), Parish Registers, vol.\ 4, p.\ 3, marriage of John Smith and Jane Bloggs (20 January 1815); digital images, Ancestry.com (\url{http://ancestry.com.au}: accessed 1 July 2018), citing Derbyshire Record Office, Matlock.},
  options      = {skipbib},
  crossref     = {coe:derb}
}
@freeform{coe:derb,
  bibliography = {Church of England (Derby, Derbyshire, England). Parish Registers. Digital images. Ancestry.com. \url{http://ancestry.com.au}: 2018},
  keywords     = {church}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{marriage} ipsum\footcite{baptism}
\printbibliography[keyword=church, title={Church Records}]
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

How do I get the 'master' source to print in my bibliography?

(I'm still a newbie, so please excuse any glaring errors or oversights!)

Comment: What would be the expected output? The two 'master' files have explicit `skipbib` options that exclude them from being shown in the bibliography. In their stead you get to see the `coe:derb` entry.

Comment: @moewe The expected output is to see the `coe:derb` bibliography entry in addition to the other entry which has not specified `skipbib`. Instead I am only seeing that entry when I want to see it AND `coe:derb`. I should have two items in my bibliography, Church of England (Derby, Derbyshire, England)... and Church of England (Spondon, Derbyshire, England)...

Comment: Ah I see. Very odd indeed. Let me investigate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `crossref = {coe:derb}` to refer to `coe:derb` from an entry, then `coe:derb` will only be added to the bibliography if it was `crossref`'d more often at least `mincrossrefs` times, where `mincrossrefs` is a `biblatex` option, whose value you can choose freely. The default value is `mincrossrefs=2`, that's why we got to see `coe:derb` in [How to set up BibLaTeX for use with 'freeform' citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438759/35864) but not here.

The solution is simple: Load `biblatex` with the option `mincrossrefs=1`.

MWE

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{freeform.dbx}
\DeclareDatamodelEntrytypes{freeform}
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{
  bibliography,
  cite,
  firstcite,
}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[freeform]{
  bibliography,
  cite,
  firstcite,
  sortkey,
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose, backend=biber, datamodel=freeform, mincrossrefs=1]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{freeform}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \printfield{bibliography}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \ifentrytype{freeform}
    {\iffieldundef{firstcite}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
       {\printfield{firstcite}}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
     \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
       \usedriver
         {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
         {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
     \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \ifentrytype{freeform}
    {\printfield{cite}}
    {\printnames{labelname}%
     \setunit*{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
     \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
       \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex,overwrite=false]{
    \map{
      \pertype{freeform}
      \step[fieldsource=bibliography]
      \step[fieldset=sortkey, origfieldval]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{sample.bib}
@freeform{baptism,
  cite         = {Church of England (Spondon, Derbs.), Parish Registers, vol.\ 9, p.\ 1, Thompson (9 June 1824).},
  firstcite    = {Church of England (Spondon, Derbyshire, England), Parish Registers, vol.\ 9, p.\ 1, baptism of Emma Thompson (9 June 1824); digital images, Ancestry.com (\url{http://ancestry.com.au}: accessed 4 July 2018), citing Derbyshire Record Office, Matlock.},
  bibliography = {Church of England (Spondon, Derbyshire, England). Parish Registers. Digital images. \textit{Ancestry.com}. \url{http://ancestry.com.au}: 2018},
  keywords     = {church}
}
@freeform{marriage,
  cite         = {Church of England (Derby, Derbs.), Parish Registers, vol.\ 4, p.\ 3, Smith-Bloggs (20 January 1815).},
  firstcite    = {Church of England (Derby, Derbyshire, England), Parish Registers, vol.\ 4, p.\ 3, marriage of John Smith and Jane Bloggs (20 January 1815); digital images, Ancestry.com (\url{http://ancestry.com.au}: accessed 1 July 2018), citing Derbyshire Record Office, Matlock.},
  options      = {skipbib},
  crossref     = {coe:derb}
}
@freeform{coe:derb,
  bibliography = {Church of England (Derby, Derbyshire, England). Parish Registers. Digital images. Ancestry.com. \url{http://ancestry.com.au}: 2018},
  keywords     = {church}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{sample.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\footcite{marriage} ipsum\footcite{baptism}
\printbibliography[keyword=church, title={Church Records}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you once again! I suppose I wouldn't have otherwise noticed the issue because eventually I will have all the crossrefs (i.e. more than 2) in place... alas!

Comment: @S.Bell Better we discover this quirk now, than not seeing it later in a large list of entries. I have edited the other answer to include the `mincrossrefs=1` since that is essential for 'split entries'.