# bibtex: can I just type what I want to see?

Tags: bibtex

Bibtex entries require different fields to be filled out. For more obscure references, this can get in the way. If I know what I want the citation entry to say, is there some way I can ddirectly enter that into a single field so that latex will accept the entry and not add question marks to my entry? For example, this citation

```
  @misc{naluwind,
    author = "{Nalu-Wind Documentation}",
    title = {{ \url{https://nalu-wind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html} retrieved on 12/7/2018}},
}
```

Yields undesirable question marks. How do I make them go away? Is there some way I can just put my entire citation in the `title` field?

[image]

Comment: There is no guaranteed way that will let you do that. The point of BibTeX is that you input the data in semantically useful bites (`author`, `title`, `year`, ...) and the style decides the output. For manual control over entries a manual `thebibliography` is probably easier. What you can do will strongly depend on the style you use. Some styles will print `????` or something else if required fields are missing others are going to be much more lenient. For `biblatex` there is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438759/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455765/35864 might also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

A more common strategy is to just fill in all fields and selectively suppress those that you don't need. You can also do this on a per-type basis (which is really what you need, in my opinion). You can find some good answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32930/is-it-possible-to-suppress-a-specific-field-from-bibtex-bbl-in-biblatex/33309) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187643/biblatex-how-can-i-suppress-some-fields-for-multiple-entry-types). This should really have been a comment, but I'm new on this forum and I don't have enough reputation "points" in order to do just that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
@online{naluwind,
  title={},
  author={{Nalu--Wind Documentation}},
  year = {{\url{https://nalu-wind.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html} retrieved on 12/7/2018, version: \url{https://github.com/Exawind/nalu-wind/commit/700c93e075c0e7c43330e77630b6c2a5789e0b0a}}},
  url={},
  }
```

[image]