# How do I modify @misc entry to allow for no year-field?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I want to cite various legal documents. It is fine to put all info in the `title` field. The document tend to have their date and year in the title so if I put something `year` field the date will be printed double. However, if I leave it empty I get "(n.d.)" at the end of the footnote and bibliography entry. If I put `year={{}},` I get a space before the final dot of the footnote and two parenthesis at the end of the printed bibliography entry.

I've seen some similar questions but I didn't get anything to work. I'm using biblatex with `backend=biber, style=authoryear`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The best solution is to make a new type for these things. See [How can I create entirely new data types with BibLaTeX/Biber?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776) for an extensive tutorial on how to do this.  For a simpler example, see [Creating Entry in Bibtex for Executive Orders](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/98551).

Comment: In the same vein as Alan Munn's comment, this answer may also be useful: [How to set up BibLaTeX for use with 'freeform' citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438794/105447).

Comment: Just repeating Alan's links because they for some reason don't appear in the linked column: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175776/, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98512/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to disable the 'n.d'/`nodate` behaviour either globally for all entry types or only for specific types with `\DeclareLabeldate`. The default definition

```
\DeclareLabeldate{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
  \literal{nodate}
}
```

writes 'n.d.' when none of the dates listed before is found. If you drop the `\literal{nodate}` from the definition, there won't be a 'n.d.'. In the MWE below the 'n.d.' is only dropped for `@misc` entries, all other types retain the default definition and therefore retain the 'n.d.' if no date is given (cf. the `applebly` `@book`).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLabeldate[misc]{%
  \field{date}
  \field{year}
  \field{eventdate}
  \field{origdate}
  \field{urldate}
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
}
@misc{law,
  title  = {Law Act 1980},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby,law}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998; Appleby n.d.; Law Act 1980//Appleby, Humphrey (n.d.). On the Importance of the Civil Service.//Law Act 1980.//Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

If you cite more legal documents, you may want to look into fleshing out the available types `@legal`, `@legislation` and `@jurisdiction` that are treated as aliases for `@misc` by the standard styles. See also [What is best practice re. handling legal sources with Biblatex/Biber for disciplines other than law?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/437824/35864).