# How to convert the citation on the UCI site?

Tags: bibtex

Currently, I am working on this [dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail). And this page gives the citation format for the users.

```
Citation Request:

Daqing Chen, Sai Liang Sain, and Kun Guo, Data mining for the online retail industry: A case study of RFM model-based customer segmentation using data mining, Journal of Database Marketing and Customer Strategy Management, Vol. 19, No. 3, pp. 197â€“208, 2012 (Published online before print: 27 August 2012. doi: 10.1057/dbm.2012.17).
```

How can I convert it in BibTeX style, or any tools, any package in R?

The answer from @Patrick.

```
@misc{Dua:2017 ,
author = "Dheeru, Dua and Karra Taniskidou, Efi",
year = "2017",
title = "{UCI} Machine Learning Repository",
url = "http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml",
institution = "University of California, Irvine, School of Information and Computer Sciences" }
```

Comment: Following citation requests like these to the letter might lead to highly inconsistent bibliographies if you want to follow several of them from different sources. That's why I suggest you take these not at face value, see them as guidance as to what data the reference should include. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263102/35864

Comment: @moewe Hi, thanks for your sharing, I am working on it.

Answer (score 1):

They have a BibTeX style definition under under [the citation policy link at the bottom of the page](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/citation_policy.html). You can modify that skeleton to suit your needs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/161721)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. And from the @Raaja 's suggestion, I Add the essential part on my question.