# Proper BibTeX citation for Pew Research Report

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, zotero

What is the proper BibTeX format for a Pew research report? [The Pew website](https://www.pewresearch.org/about/terms-and-conditions/) says:

> 2. Citation. “Report Title.” Pew Research Center, Washington, D.C. (Publication date) URL.

My entry currently looks like

```
@techreport{pewresearchcenter_2019_Americansfavor,
  title = {Americans Favor Mobile Devices over Desktops and Laptops for Getting News},
  author = {{Pew Research Center}},
  year = {2019},
  month = Nov,
  day = 19,
  address = {{Washington, D.C.}},
  url = {https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/11/19/americans-favor-mobile-devices-over-desktops-and-laptops-for-getting-news/},
  language = {en-US}
}
```

But this doesn't produce the full date in the bibliography. It only looks like this:

> Pew Research Center. 2019. Americans Favor Mobile Devices over Desktops
> and Laptops for Getting News. Technical Report. Washington, D.C.
> https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2019/11/19/americans-favor-mobile-devices-over-desktops-and-laptops-for-getting-news/

How do I get the full date, and for it not to say "Technical Report"?

(I would also like it to export properly from Zotero, but that's a problem for another day.)

Comment: As always, the exact output will depend on the bibliography style you use. So you may have to experiment a bit (and/or check out in the style documentation or source code which fields are supported). I should mention that I know of no BibTeX style that supports a `day` field (neither does `biblatex`).

Comment: As for the *legal status* of the "please cite as" in the ToS I cannot help you, but from a purely scientific/bibliographic viewpoint I think it is absurd to force a certain style of reference unto people. If you were to follow the guidance in the ToS to the letter you could not cite any Pew work in an article using APA style, because APA style requires a different result. Surely that cannot be the desired outcome. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263102/35864. ...

Comment: ... The proper format for a reference should be determined by the reference style. The author of the work that is cited has control over all the raw entry data, but should not ave control over the final presentation.

Comment: @Adam_G in what sense do you mean "exported properly"?