# Adding a reference without Bibtex file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I would like to add a reference for a dataset I am using in my project. As per the dataset sit, they have asked to include the below citation.

> Citation Request:
>
> Davide Anguita, Alessandro Ghio, Luca Oneto, Xavier Parra and Jorge L. Reyes-Ortiz. A Public Domain Dataset for Human Activity Recognition Using Smartphones. 21th European Symposium on Artificial Neural Networks, Computational Intelligence and Machine Learning, ESANN 2013. Bruges, Belgium 24-26 April 2013.

How can I convert this to a bibtex to be added into .bib file?

Comment: Generally speaking you can read these citation request in two ways: literal and not-so-literal. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263102/35864. If you want to read it literally, you need to fudge an entry or work with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438759/35864. If you read it not-so-literally you can go for https://gist.github.com/moewew/542d4fda71b68cc7dbfede2c6907e8d3.

Comment: See the "Basic approach" in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) answer to make cites and a reference section  without a .bib file. See the other methods to uses a .bib file (indeed better if you need manage many references).